# Dynamically changing website background after certain time using php

Tags: php, while-loop, sleep

Hi i am trying to change my webpage background after certain time using php
here i tried using while loop but its not working neither showing any error.
thanks for helping me

```
<?php
function random_color_part() {
    return str_pad( dechex( mt_rand( 0, 255 ) ), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function random_color() {
    return random_color_part() . random_color_part() . random_color_part();
}


function final_done(){
    $yourcolor = random_color();

    $styleBlock = sprintf('<style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color:%s;
            }',$yourcolor);
    echo $styleBlock;

}
while (true) {
    final_done();
    sleep(3);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this with PHP. PHP is a server side language, once it is executed, it's done, it won't do anything else on it's own. For this, you'll likely need JavaScript.

Comment: Look for "css animation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a confusion here: php is supposed to be on a server side, while your are using it to define a HTML data, which is used on the client side.

The way you are using it should be done in a client side language, like javascript. The way it is programatically thought is good, but confused in a client/server schema.

So you basically have two ways to do it:

- The "normal one", using javascript to make the same loop changing background color.
- The "php one", which sould not be recommended, in which you can define background color on each page load. Note that this one won't allows you to use a timed loop on client side.

Comment: means looping php function using js?

Comment: No, php is server side, but change backgroup color is client side. It's different.
You should define js function to do it, not php code.

Comment: You can use some JS code as described in this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250647/change-background-color-between-red-and-green-every-second). But indeed, php is only server side, and you have to use client side language in this case.